# Erratic behaviour when importing JSON natively from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I've come across a very strange behaviour when loading a JSON file into javascript while working on a React project. I'm hoping that someone here can explain what is going on and how to properly access data from my JSON data store.

I have a JSON file with product data:

```
{
        "product-type": "harness",
        [...]
        "build-options": {
            "product-family": [
                "edge8"
            ],
            [...],
            "fiber-type": [
                "om4",
                "os2",
                "om5",
                "om3"
            ],
            "leg1-length": [
                "150mm",
                "type1",
                "900mm",
                "600mm",
                "1200mm",
                "type2",
                "type3",
                "type5",
                "300mm",
                "1500mm",
                "2500mm",
                "1800mm"
            ],
            "connector1-pinning": [
                "nopin"
            ]
        }
    }
```

It is loaded in the my code as follows:

```
import definitionData from './definitionData.json';
```

However, when loaded, some of the arrays in the build-options object show empty, while some do not.

```
{
    "product-family": [
        "edge8"
    ],
    "fiber-type": [
        "om4",
        "os2",
        "om5",
        "om3"
    ],
    "fiber-count": [
        "08"
    ],
    [...],
    "harness-type": [],
    "leg1-length": [],
    "leg1-type": [],
    "connector1-type": [],
    "connector1-fiber-count": [
        "simplex"
    ],
    "connector1-pinning": [
        "nopin"
    ]
}
```

Interestingly, depending on how I access it in this first component, the data displays in completely inconsistent ways. Here are three examples:

- If we do `console.log(myDefinition['build-options'])` we get the above example.
- If we try to access the object using forEach, we can log the proper values:
  `Object.entries(definitionData[index]['build-options']).forEach((entry)=> console.log(entry[0], entry[1]))`

```
>>...
>> fiber-type > (4) ['om4', 'os2', 'om5', 'om3']
>> leg1-length > (12) ['150mm', 'type1', '900mm', '600mm', '1200mm', 'type2', 'type3', 'type5', '300mm', '1500mm', '2500mm', '1800mm']
>>...
```

- And now even more puzzling, if we instead try to access the whole entry, javascript will recognize the length of the array, but won't be able to see it's values:
  `Object.entries(definitionData[index]['build-options']).forEach((entry)=> console.log(entry))`

```
['leg1-length', Array(12)]
0: "leg1-length"
1: []
```

- In all the above examples, some data is still never properly loaded:

```
(2) ['connector1-type', Array(0)]
0: "connector1-type"
1: []

connector1-type > []
```

I've also tried using `require()` but the same behaviour persists.

I assume this erratic behaviour has to do with some particularity of reference passing and how the memory is being accessed within Javascript, but I don't understand why or how.

**Can someone explain this behaviour? And also give an example of how one should properly load a JSON object in a way that it is fully visible and behaves as expected of a Javascript object?**

Comment: `JSON.parse(yourInputString)` will return a real, full javascript object (or an error if the input is not valid JSON.)

Answer (score -1):

After some more experimenting I think I found the motive for this behaviour.

Basically, this apparent erratic behaviour is caused by a few misunderstandings on my part:

- First and most important, `Object.entries()` only creates a **shallow copy** of an object, and this explains why when using `forEach` the object displays properly, or semi properly.
- Second, the data is actually completely accessible as long as it is passed by reference. My original trouble in accessing it which made me believe it was not loaded properly came from me not knowing which JS operations were copying the object and which weren't.
- Lastly, there seems to be a bug in the way console.log() displays some JSON objects. Sometimes it just won't display an array held by an attribute depending on some esoteric property of the key that I still haven't been able to figure out.

Comment: Lots of inaccuracies in this answer.

There is no such thing as a JSON object.  It's either a JSON string, or an object.

"Passing by reference" or copying the object is irrelevant.

`Object.entries()` does not create a shallow copy; it returns two arrays, one containing all the keys, the other containing all their values.  Your code ignores the second array. 
There is not a bug in the console.  Most or all modern browsers will collapse large, complex objects for easier reading; you can click the little triangle next to it or its keys to expand them and see the full data.